# How to sort items in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, backbone.js, underscore.js

i am working on learn backbone.js, so i decided to make mi own Todo app using backbone.js and a localstorage plugin. I already have the Todo app in wich you can add and remove todos, now I am working on make them sortable in done and not done tasks. But the problem is that i can't find a way to do it. i created a method in the view called sort_done()

```
    sort_done: function(){
    var done = this.collection.where({done: true});
    console.log(done);
}
```

But don't know how could i udate the view in order to just show thedone or not done tasks, i appreciate if someone could give me some advice in how i can manage this kind of ´problem. I also leave the model, collection and views js so you can take a look.

Model:

```
    var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        title: "An empyt task..",
        done: false
    },

    validate: function(attrs){
        if(! $.trim(attrs.title)){
            return "The task has no title"
        }
    }
});

var task = new Task;
```

Collection:

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Task,

localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-collection")
});

var tasks = new Tasks();
```

Views:

```
   var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",

    template: _.template( $('#task').html() ),

    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );

        this.$el.html( template );

        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click .icon-checkbox': 'toggleState',
        'click .task_title': 'editTask',
        'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
        'click  .close_btn': 'clear'
    },

    toggleState: function(e){
        var $checkbox = $(e.target);
        this.model.save('done', !this.model.get('done'));

    },

    editTask: function(e){
        this.task = $(e.target);
        this.editBox = this.task.next();
        this.editInput = this.editBox.find('.edit');

        $(".task_title").removeClass("display__none");
        $(".editBox").removeClass("edit_box__editing");
        this.task.addClass("display__none")
        this.editBox.addClass("edit_box__editing");
        this.editInput.attr('placeholder', this.task.text()).focus();
    },

    updateOnEnter: function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            this.close();
        }
    },

    close: function(){
        var value = this.editInput.val();
        if(!value){
            this.task.removeClass("display__none")
            this.editBox.removeClass("edit_box__editing");
        }else{
            this.model.save({title: value});
            this.task.removeClass("display__none")
            this.editBox.removeClass("edit_box__editing");
        }
    },

    clear:function(){
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});

var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tasks',

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on()
    },

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

        return this;

    },

    addOne: function(task){
        var taskView = new TaskView({ model: task });
        this.$el.append( taskView.render().el );
    }
});

var AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#todos',

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    events:{
        'click #add': 'addTask',
        'click #filter_done': 'sort_done',
        'keypress #inputTask': 'updateOnEnter'
    },

    addTask: function(){

        var taskTitle = $('#inputTask'). val();
        $('#inputTask').val(""); //clear the input

        if($.trim(taskTitle) === ''){//check if the input has some text in it
            this.displayMessage("Todo's can not be empty");
        }else{
            var task = new Task( {title: taskTitle} ); // create the task model
            this.collection.create(task); //add the model to the collection         
        }
    },

    displayMessage: function(msg){
        $('#inputTask').focus().attr("placeholder", msg);
    },

    updateOnEnter: function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            this.addTask();
        }
    },

    sort_done: function(){
        var done = this.collection.where({done: true});
        console.log(done);
    }

});


var tasksView = new TasksView( {collection: tasks} );
var addTask = new AddTask( {collection: tasks} );
```

Thank yoou very much!

Comment: Backbone.js depends on Underscore.js. You could use the [_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) method.

Comment: Yeah, but actually my problem is that using  the _.sortBy method of underscore or the this.collection.where({done: true});, i dont know how to update the view with the returned object

Answer (score 1):

When you call `collection.where` your collection is not filtered, it just returning the filtered models (not changing the initial collection), so for your problem you have to do like this :

```
initialize: function(){
    this.render();
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); // here I change the event to reset
},

...

sort_done: function(){
    var done = this.collection.where({done: true});
    this.collection.reset(done);
    console.log(done);
}
```

Comment: but if i trigger sort i am going to render the view as it is, so it is going to render as it is because im not passing the rendered collection or something like that

Comment: No, your collection is already linked to your view `var tasksView = new TasksView( {collection: tasks} );` so in the `tasksView` render function you can get the collection bu calling `this.collection`.

Comment: i already tried but i render the same view, not sorted, and also my view render after the previwsly one rendered so i am getting duplicated content